# Angular Material with Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

Are there any options to use Angular Material with new Angular 4?

Official [material.angularjs.org](http://material.angularjs.org) says:

> Angular Material recently released Version 1 which we consider to be stable and ready for production use. Developers should note that Angular Material v1 works only with Angular 1.x.

And with regard to Angular 2:

> Angular Material v2 development is also in progress at the `angular/material2` GitHub repository

What about Angular 4? Do you think we can bind somehow Angular 1.x and Angular 4 in one project to bring Angular 4 new features and keep using the awesome Angular Material framework?

Comment: There is still no Angular4 documentation online. Materials team did not realese information about how, when and why they will implement Angular4 support.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can refer to the **Getting Started** guide from [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md). This documentation is updated to support **angular v4.0.0**

Some Material components depend on the **Angular animations module** in order to be able to do more advanced transitions. If you want these animations to work in your app, you have to install the `@angular/animations` module and include the `BrowserAnimationsModule` in your app from `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.

Comment: Hi, is it safe to use @angular/material (which is based on Angular 5) in an Angular project that uses LTS version 4.4.6?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to know also the answer to @danrt, i'm facing compilations issues

Comment: @PedroTainha just to let you know, we switched to angular 5 to avoid any issues

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's what I'm facing and we have to change also.

Answer (score 5):

In December 2016, when the Angular team was running around telling everyone to stop saying "Angular 2" and just say "Angular", I kind of thought it was silly marketing stuff.

In reading through questions on this site, however, I am beginning to see the rational for their plea. Angular 1.x to Angular 2 represented a complete rewrite, an entirely re-architected framework that broke just about everything. Adding to this is the switch to semver, which meant that new major versions numbers would be coming more rapidly.

In short, what I think they were trying to head off was the line of thinking that "Angular 4 is to Angular 2 as Angular 2 was to Angular 1", which is definitely not true.

This perception problem is also what led them to code name 4.0 "invisible makeover".

So, when you see packages that are designed for Angular2, most of them will probably work also with Angular 4. And if there are ng4 changes that break those packages, you will either quickly see releases to address those... or you'll have your answer about whether that package is well-maintained enough to use in your project.

Comment: I do agreement with your statement. However, my point was about Angular Material library not Angular it self, see now angular material official says that you can use is stable only for 1.x and on GitHub you can find beta version for Angular 2, but there is Angular 4 already on the market and they still don't have Angular Material stable build even for Angular 2.

Comment: Yes, but my point was that Angular 4 is more like angular 2.5 than the name would suggest. The material2 project works just fine with Angular 4 (or it will as soon as they release the next beta (for now you can point to master). From your statements, you seem to be viewing Angular 4 as a bigger upgrade than it actually is.

Comment: Yes, maybe I did. I guess it just necessary to play with Angular 4 to Material 2 combination and see how it will work.

Comment: to add to this, Angular 1x is now just AngularJS and Angular 2, 4 ( there is no v3) and beyond, is just Angular. To clarify, to refer to Angular 2 or Angular 4 as distinct and separate versions of Angular is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

I am also working with Angular 4.0.0 and CLI 1.0.0, it works fine. Just to say that strange behaviours like unstyled checkbox mentioned above occur because theming your components is mandatory. You can work with prebuilt angular material themes or generate your own. Just include the stylesheet in your index.html and you will see the magic.

more info on angular material theming can be found here : https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Do you have a decent guide you could point me to? I created a project with the CLI and then added references to both @angular/material and @angular/animations. I then imported a pre-built theme in my styles.css. When I ran ng serve I got all kinds of errors. Wondering if you could help me out with it

Comment: what do you mean by "added references" ? did you actually install @angular/material and @angular/animations with NPM ? if it is the case, did you check your imports in your `app.module.ts`  ?

Comment: Yes of course Npm. Anyway I figured it out. I was importing the incorrect Module (I had been following older guides which instructed me to load the wrong module(s)). That being said, I dropped material design and used materialize-css instead. The beta version of material design had issues so I had to stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

I just have started work with angular 4.0.0 (using angular cli 1.0.0) and tried to use it with material 2.0.0-beta2. It works ok except some bugs in UI:

1. Material Checkbox looks awful, it has native checkbox inside it own ([Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AtLauuYoOxJMOIZ3LflmZpzWLn9OQ7rtKtc))

I will update this post in case of meet something unstable.
It seems that you can try https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can download or fork [angular-quickstart](https://github.com/rajexp/angular-quickstart) boilerplate from [here](https://github.com/rajexp/angular-quickstart)
In this project have the latest stable support of angular material 2.0.0-beta.6 and angular 4.0.0 .
It was pretty difficult to find the correct settings for latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Do This:

```
npm install --save @angular/animations

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

 //in app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
  ...
})
export class YourAppModule { }
```

Again import Material Module. Like

```
import: [MaterialModule.forRoot()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the angular 2/4 sites are io try this

https://material.angular.io/

Comment: how ever this will redirect to github-quickstart page only

Answer (score 0):

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Add that to your css file :) . I had the same thing happen to me. Just need a theme fix that issue.

Comment: how do you deal with missing md-content?

Comment: You could just make your own element in angular :) . Or use md-card-content